# Null object in hasOne relationship strange behaviour

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a User `resource` in `Laravel` where the an User `object` has a nested Login `object`.

My User `class` have these `attributes`:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'nickname', 'dob',
];

public function login(){
    return $this->hasOne(Login::class, 'id');
}
```

My Login `class` is like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password',
];

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'login');
}
```

This is my UserController index `method`:

```
public function index()
{
    $usr= User::with('login')->get();

    return response()->json(['user' => $usr], 200);
}
```

With an `object` that have a Login it works pretty well, however, with a User that doesnt have a Login, it returns a User that have the last Login inserted on the Login table.

Why `Laravel` is doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to swap the relationships:

```
public function login(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Login::class, 'login');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'login');
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work. in laravel.log I get: Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'login.login' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `login` where `login`.`login` in ...

Comment: What are the foreign key columns in `login` and `user`?

Comment: inside user table, i have one column called login, that is a fk and references the login table, id column, that is a pk

Comment: thanks!!! it really worked. if you have any site that teaches these relationships well, i would thank you a lot.

Comment: Did you look at the Laravel documentation?

Comment: i started studying laravel a few days ago in a Udemy course, and dont know yet how these relationships are called. now, i'll look at Laravel docs first. thanks.